# PDF link does not open

Tags: html, pdf, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I placed this link inside a page to open a pdf, but it does not open. When I inspect the dom and click the highlighted href, it does open. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="document-wrapper">
    <a alt="One Pager" class="document btn btn-link" href="/assets/asset_contents/5203/original/test.pdf?1405610951">One Pager</a>
</div>
```

Comment: try opening it in a new window by adding `target="_blank"` to the `<a>` tag

Comment: That still does not seem to work.

Comment: Are you experiencing this on all browsers?

Comment: Yes it seems to happen on chrome and IE

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any click handlers for anchors which prevents defaults ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

for open the pdf in a new windows

```
<a target=\"_blank\" href="example.pdf" title="some title"></a>
```

if you want to put some linked image try this:

```
<a target=\"_blank\" href="example.pdf" title="some title"><img src="adobepdf.png" height="30" width="30"></a>
```

good luck